# Can't mark custom comment flag as helpful after the comment has been deleted automatically

Tags: feature-request, comments, flags, moderator-tools, comment-flags

What happened:

1. A user voted to close a question as duplicate, generating an automatic comment "Does this answer your question?"
2. Another user flagged that question with a custom comment flag
3. The question was closed as a duplicate, which removes the automatic comment

Now, the comment flag is still pending, but I can't mark it as helpful (which would happen when I delete it). I can edit it (that marked the flag as helpful), but moderators shouldn't edit comments unless absolutely necessary; I can decline it (but I don't want to) and I can probably undelete the comment and then delete it via the flag, but that is rather cumbersome. I think the UI should give me some option to mark the flag as helpful

[image]

Comment: Already reported on the moderator team: https://stackoverflow.com/c/moderators/q/3362. I've been frustrated by this on *multiple* occasions. It's broken in a surprising number of ways. (Including the fact that the flag was *already* marked "helpful", and, despite what the UI options suggest, you have *no way* of actually declining it.) I've added the [needs-staff] tag to the bug report on the mod team, which (I hope) is the equivalent of [status-review].

Comment: @Cody so some bugs/requests are posted only in that private team, instead of here? (just asking, don't really care as I don't really have any use and neither can I help with mod tools bugs/requests)

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar yes, that happens if the 'public' is not supposed to know about the tools.

Comment: OK, but in this case it's a common and known tool.